# How can I restrict Internet access on a ZyWALL USG 50?

Tags: firewall

I have a ZyWALL USG 50.

I believe it is capable of restricting Internet access. For example when a user attempts to visit a website they need to first present a username and password that is allowed to access the Internet.

I can't see any documentation on it, or how it is set up.

Is there someone who has some experience doing such things with a ZyWALL USG 50?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to enable Forced User Authentication.  Quoting from the help:

> Forced User Authentication
>   Instead of making users for which user-aware policies have been configured go to the ZyWALL Login screen manually, you can configure the ZyWALL to display the Login screen automatically whenever it routes HTTP traffic for anyone who has not logged in yet.
>
> Note:
>   This works with HTTP traffic only. The ZyWALL does display the Login screen when users attempt to send other kinds of traffic.
>
> The ZyWALL does not automatically route the request that prompted the login, however, so users have to make this request again.

You can do this from the Auth. Policy section in the USG (where you can also find the Help link.)  FYI: I've worked with USG 20s, 50s and 100s and am fairly familiar with them, but haven't tried doing this.